# iPhone Safari full size & PC versions different

Tags: child-theme

[This site](http://test.incredibleconcepts.com.au/) displays the correct logo at top left of the content in Chrome, but displays the incorrect logo in Safari on an iPhone, at full size browsing.  The incorrect logo says "Dandelion".  The correct logo says "Incredible Concepts".

The incorrect logo belongs to the Wordpress theme's parent theme.  The child theme is activated.

If Safari is viewing at full size desktop version, it should show the same content as Chrome on a PC, and this content is produced by the Wordpress child theme.

If the theme had reverted to the parent theme, the header would be totally different.  Why is the logo the only incorrect item?

Comment: This is a basic CSS question and not related to WordPress.

Comment: This sounds like it could be a bug in the way WordPress is handling child themes (though I could *easily* be wrong). I'd also recommend posting in wordpress.org and/or the theme's support forums.

Comment: @Chris_O: It is precisely related to Wordpress, as it is a Child theme specific, not CSS specific.

Comment: maybe your parent theme has a mobile specific css file where the logo should be updated also in the child theme

Answer (score 0):

as user15... sugested you may have a mobile specific CSS in your child or parent theme - that is conflicting with the logo, have you tried loading the site from the desktop pc with cross browser plat form site ? http://www.onbile.com/info/tools-for-testing-how-your-site-looks-on-mobile-devices/ and http://www.fingermarketing.com/comparemysite.php tools the let you see how your website looks in mobile ? and please try loading the site in desktop safar browser - www.apple.com/safari/ download it on your pc and try running the site in safari browser. might help you detect problem -

The second thing is apple safari blocks many javascript's that are safe - but it blocks them it has some unsual behavior to handle java - make sure you are not showing your logo enclosing  it with java -

if you define in more details with code and css it will be much better to assist you.